# Converting pandas Dataframe to nested json key pair

Tags: python, json, pandas

Here is a sample data from a csv file, where every generation is children of previous generation.

```
parant,gen1,gen2,get3,gen4,gen5,gen6
query1,AggregateExpression,abc,def,emg,cdf,bcf
query1,And,cse,rds,acd,,
query2,Arithmetic,cbd,rsd,msd,,
query2,Average,as,vs,ve,ew,
query2,BinaryExpression,avsd,sfds,sdf,,
query2,Comparison,sdfs,sdfsx,,,
query3,Count,sfsd,,,,
query3,methods1,add,asd,fdds,sdf,sdf
query3,methods1,average,sdfs,bf,fd,
query4,methods2,distinct,cz,asd,ada,
query4,methods2,eq,sdfs,sdfxcv,sdf,rtyr
query4,methods3,eq,vcx,xcv,cdf,
```

I need to create a json file of following format, where parents are the index and children are always list of dictionaries and there is a size for the last generation which is calculated no. of time their parent appear (in previous generation).
Example of the first row breakdown:

```
{
"name": "query1",
"children": [
    {
        "name": "AggregateExpression",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "abc",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "def",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "name": "emg",
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "cdf",
                                        "children": [
                                            {
                                                "name": "bcf", "size": 1
                                            }
                                        ]

                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I have tried to use groupby() and to_json() but was not able to complete. But still struggling to build the logic if I need to use lambda or looping. Any suggestion or solution is welcome. Thanks.